# Is computing natural gradient equivalent to deriving directional derivative?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, derivative, gradient

It seems to me that natural gradient is simply derived from directional derivative. For example, for a vector $v$,

$\tilde{\nabla} f \cdot v = G^{-1} \nabla f \cdot v = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$

If they are equivalent, why do we need two terms for the same thing?

References:

Directional derivative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)

Why Natural Gradient? (http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/amari-why.pdf)

Natural Gradient Works Efficiently in Learning (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.452.7280&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I think the difference is a bit subtle, but natural gradients are suppose to be an *intrinsic* properties of the function $f$ and do not depend on the parameterisation of $f$. In particular, the intuition is we want to know the curvature of $f$ independently of a choice of coordinate system. Whereas directional derivatives as defined by your definition require specification of a vector $v$ and so also are explicitly calculated with respect to vector space and a coordinate system centered around $x$.

Natural gradients don't need a function $f$ in general to be specified, only a geometric structure (usually in this context a Riemannian manifold). To actually do any calculations we still need to choose a coordinate system. In that example of Amari's of calculating the Riemannian metric tensor $G$ when the geometric structure being studied is $\mathbb{R}^2$, to obtain an explicit form for $G$ we need to choose coordinates. Since we are studying  $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to polar coordinates, the Riemannian metric tensor is not constant. To put it another way, polar coordinates introduce an artificial curvature on $\mathbb{R}^2$ even though the underlying space is intrinsically flat.

People with a background in differential geometry (like Amari) seem to really care about these coordinate-free, intrinsic definitions. Sometimes it is not possible to have global coordinate system for geometric objects that they study. My impression is that the geometric structures of distributions which arise in statistics there is often a natural and important global coordinate system.

**EDIT:**

It seems directional derivative on a manifold is not well-defined. You generally have two choices: Lie Derivatives or Affine Connections.

Without fully learning DG, the main thing to realize is that it is reasonable to prefer methods and algorithms that gives the same answer regardless of the representation of the problem. Mackay (2003) Ch. 4 calls these methods covariant. DG folks would say coordinate-free. I *think* (please somebody chime in) that Natural Gradients are really Affine Connections (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection). And I think that this is where the word "covariant" came from in this context going back to Mackay (2003) and before: From Wikipedia

> an affine connection is simply a covariant derivative or (linear)
>   connection on the tangent bundle

Typical setting in ML is the manifold of distributions under some representation (the weights) and usually something like the KL divergence as a target loss.

Comment: That's also my intuition in the beginning, especially for the second part (directional derivative): when I work out the gradient in polar coordinate, I always have the mapping from euclidean coordinate in mind.

Comment: For the natural gradient, does the calculation of $G$ require knowing the function $f$? In "Why Natural Gradient?", the calculation of $G$ is done in Equation 15 and the function $f$ is not even defined yet. This really confuses me.

Comment: I have tried to elaborate on this in the answer but the structure being studied is not a  function $f$ but rather $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I really like "To actually do any calculations we still need to choose a coordinate system", "polar coordinates introduce an artificial curvature". Appreciate that @MachineEpsilon. For "to obtain an explicit form for $G$", it seems that we need the mapping between polar coord and euclidean coord. Why does the euclidean coord (always) appear and seem necessary?

Comment: "the geometric structures of distributions which arise in statistics there is often a natural and important global coordinate system." This sounds crucial. I am thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the directional derivative

$$ Df(x, v) =  \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h} $$

it is not obvious that $Df$ should have any special structure.  On the other hand, the mapping

$$ v \mapsto \nabla f(x) \dot v $$

has **a lot** of obvious structure - it is a **linear** map.

The point of these two definitions is that **the gradient exists**.  I.e., we can only have a thing called a gradient vector **if** the directional derivative is a linear map.  It didn't have to be, we could have found ourselves in a universe where directional derivative have much worse behaviour, and mathematics would be a lot more difficult.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand. Your answer is explaining "gradient" and "directional derivative". I agree with what you said. But my original question is more about the "natural gradient" (the $\tilde \nabla f$) For me, there is only one gradient and we can derive it from the directional derivative. I don't know why we need to have gradient and natural gradient.

Comment: I have never heard of this distinction, even though I studied differential geometry in graduate school.  What's the source for this terminology?

Comment: @MatthewDrury It's from information geometry and it's application to the natural gradient descent algorithm described by Amari in the paper "Natural Gradient Works Efficiently in Learning " that LKS cites above. Section 2 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3584.pdf gives you a brief  overview or if you can get a copy there's a longer summary of the area in Chapter 12 of Amari's 2016 book.

Comment: @MatthewDrury "never heard of this distinction" that's my point. It seems to me that there is only one kind of "gradient" which is from the definition of directional derivative. I don't understand why the "natural gradient" paper needs to emphasize the distinction. To be clear, the notation in my equation above is $\tilde \nabla f$ is the "natural gradient" and $\nabla f$ is the "gradient" with Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification LKS, I apologize for not understanding your question.  I think a differential geometer would agree with you on that one.

Comment: The problem is also very subtle to me. If you have comment on this distinction from the viewpoint of differential geometry, I am happy to know.